# How can I edit the three.js AsciiRenderer (AsciiEffect) so it has a higher resolution at the same aspect ratio?

Tags: next.js, three.js, tailwind-css, ascii, react-three-fiber

I'm trying to add the react three AsciiRenderer to STL models in my next.js project and if I make the resolution higher than the default (0.15) it seems to squish the [width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haQXV.gif). In dev tools I was able to make the letterSpacing a bit wider and that seemed to solve it, but I'm unable to access that property in my code. It always stays at -1.

I'm pretty new to code, so I may be looking for a solution in the completely wrong area.

Here is my component with the 3d model and the AsciiRenderer

```
import { ArticactSelector } from "@/components/ArtifactDatabase/ArtifactSelector";
import { ViewPortal } from "@/components/ArtifactDatabase/ViewPortal";
import { PageHeader } from "@/components/PageHeader";
import { ArtifactDatabaseIcon } from "@/public/icons";
import Image from "next/image";

export const metadata = {
  title: "Artifact Database",
  description: "",
};

export default function Page() {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center w-full px-4">
      <div className="">
        <PageHeader
          name={metadata.title}
          description={metadata.description}
          icon={<ArtifactDatabaseIcon className="w-6 h-6" />}
        />
      </div>

      <div className="flex flex-row w-auto place-content-center md:px-12">
        <div className="flex w-full">
          <ViewPortal />
        </div>

        <ArticactSelector />
      </div>
      <div className="flex mt-12 border-1 border-sand-300 border-t-[10px] h-auto py-4 justify-center">
        <Image
          src="/gifs/cube.gif"
          alt={""}
          width={150}
          height={150}
          className="image-pixelated dark:invert"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the AsciiRenderer

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useThree, useFrame } from '@react-three/fiber';
import { AsciiEffect } from 'three-stdlib';

function AsciiRenderer({
  renderIndex = 1,
  bgColor = 'black',
  fgColor = 'white',
  characters = ' .:-+*=%@#',
  invert = true,
  color = false,
  resolution = 0.15,
  // spacing = '',
}) {
  // Reactive state
  const {
    size,
    gl,
    scene,
    camera,
  } = useThree(); // Create effect

  const effect = React.useMemo(() => {
    const effect = new AsciiEffect(gl, characters, {
      invert,
      color,
      resolution,
    });
    effect.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
    effect.domElement.style.top = '0px';
    effect.domElement.style.left = '0px';
    effect.domElement.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    return effect;
  }, [characters, invert, color, resolution,]); // Styling

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    effect.domElement.style.color = fgColor;
    effect.domElement.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
    effect.domElement.style.letterSpacing = "0px";
  }, [fgColor, bgColor, letterSpacing]); // Append on mount, remove on unmount

  React.useEffect(() => {
    gl.domElement.style.opacity = '0';
    gl.domElement.parentNode.appendChild(effect.domElement);
    return () => {
      gl.domElement.style.opacity = '1';
      gl.domElement.parentNode.removeChild(effect.domElement);
    };
  }, [effect]); // Set size

  // React.useEffect(() => {
  //   effect.domElement.style.letterSpacing = spacing;
  // }, [spacing]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    effect.setSize(size.width, size.height);
  }, [effect, size]); // Take over render-loop (that is what the index is for)

  useFrame(state => {
    effect.render(scene, camera);
  }, renderIndex); // return something to not break type signatures

  return /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(React.Fragment, null);
}

export { AsciiRenderer };
```

Here is the AsciiEffect

```
class AsciiEffect {
  constructor(renderer, charSet = " .:-=+*#%@", options = {}) {
    const fResolution = options["resolution"] || 0.15;
    const iScale = options["scale"] || 1;
    const bColor = options["color"] || false;
    const bAlpha = options["alpha"] || false;
    const bBlock = options["block"] || false;
    const bInvert = options["invert"] || false;
    // const strResolution = options["strResolution"] || "low";
    // const spacing = options["spacing"] || "0px";
    let width, height;
    const domElement = document.createElement("div");
    domElement.style.cursor = "default";
    // domElement.style.letterSpacing = "0px";
    const oAscii = document.createElement("table");
    domElement.appendChild(oAscii);
    let iWidth, iHeight;
    let oImg;
    this.setSize = function(w, h) {
      width = w;
      height = h;
      renderer.setSize(w, h);
      initAsciiSize();
    };
    this.render = function(scene, camera) {
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
      asciifyImage(oAscii);
    };
    this.domElement = domElement;
    function initAsciiSize() {
      iWidth = Math.floor(width * fResolution);
      iHeight = Math.floor(height * fResolution);
      oCanvas.width = iWidth;
      oCanvas.height = iHeight;
      oImg = renderer.domElement;
      if (oImg.style.backgroundColor) {
        oAscii.rows[0].cells[0].style.backgroundColor = oImg.style.backgroundColor;
        oAscii.rows[0].cells[0].style.color = oImg.style.color;
      }
      // oAscii.cellSpacing = 0;
      // oAscii.cellPadding = 0;
      const oStyle = oAscii.style;
      oStyle.whiteSpace = "pre";
      oStyle.margin = "0px";
      oStyle.padding = "0px";
      oStyle.letterSpacing = "0px";
      oStyle.fontFamily = strFont;
      oStyle.fontSize = fFontSize + "px";
      oStyle.lineHeight = fLineHeight + "px";
      oStyle.textAlign = "left";
      oStyle.textDecoration = "none";
    }
    const aDefaultCharList = " .,:;i1tfLCG08@".split("");
    const aDefaultColorCharList = " CGO08@".split("");
    const strFont = "";
    const oCanvasImg = renderer.domElement;
    const oCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    if (!oCanvas.getContext) {
      return;
    }
    const oCtx = oCanvas.getContext("2d");
    if (!oCtx.getImageData) {
      return;
    }
    let aCharList = bColor ? aDefaultColorCharList : aDefaultCharList;
    if (charSet)
      aCharList = charSet;
    const fFontSize = 2;
    const fLineHeight = 2 / fResolution * iScale;

    
   
    // if (strResolution == "low") {
    //   switch (iScale) {
    //     case 1:
    //       fLetterSpacing = -1;
    //       break;
    //     case 2:
    //     case 3:
    //       fLetterSpacing = -2.1;
    //       break;
    //     case 4:
    //       fLetterSpacing = -3.1;
    //       break;
    //     case 5:
    //       fLetterSpacing = -4.15;
    //       break;
    //   }
    // }
    // if (strResolution == "medium") {
    //   switch (iScale) {
    //     case 1:
    //       fLetterSpacing = 0;
    //       break;
    //     case 2:
    //       fLetterSpacing = -1;
    //       break;
    //     case 3:
    //       fLetterSpacing = -1.04;
    //       break;
    //     case 4:
    //     case 5:
    //       fLetterSpacing = -2.1;
    //       break;
    //   }
    // }
    // if (strResolution == "high") {
    //   switch (iScale) {
    //     case 1:
    //     case 2:
    //       fLetterSpacing = 0;
    //       break;
    //     case 3:
    //     case 4:
    //     case 5:
    //       fLetterSpacing = -1;
    //       break;
    //   }
    // }
    function asciifyImage(oAscii2) {
      oCtx.clearRect(0, 0, iWidth, iHeight);
      oCtx.drawImage(oCanvasImg, 0, 0, iWidth, iHeight);
      const oImgData = oCtx.getImageData(0, 0, iWidth, iHeight).data;
      let strChars = "";
      for (let y = 0; y < iHeight; y += 2) {
        for (let x = 0; x < iWidth; x++) {
          const iOffset = (y * iWidth + x) * 4;
          const iRed = oImgData[iOffset];
          const iGreen = oImgData[iOffset + 1];
          const iBlue = oImgData[iOffset + 2];
          const iAlpha = oImgData[iOffset + 3];
          let iCharIdx;
          let fBrightness;
          fBrightness = (0.3 * iRed + 0.59 * iGreen + 0.11 * iBlue) / 255;
          if (iAlpha == 0) {
            fBrightness = 1;
          }
          iCharIdx = Math.floor((1 - fBrightness) * (aCharList.length - 1));
          if (bInvert) {
            iCharIdx = aCharList.length - iCharIdx - 1;
          }
          let strThisChar = aCharList[iCharIdx];
          if (strThisChar === void 0 || strThisChar == " ")
            strThisChar = "&nbsp;";
          if (bColor) {
            strChars += "<span style='color:rgb(" + iRed + "," + iGreen + "," + iBlue + ");" + (bBlock ? "background-color:rgb(" + iRed + "," + iGreen + "," + iBlue + ");" : "") + (bAlpha ? "opacity:" + iAlpha / 255 + ";" : "") + "'>" + strThisChar + "</span>";
          } else {
            strChars += strThisChar;
          }
        }
        strChars += "<br/>";
      }
      oAscii2.innerHTML = `<tr><td style="display:block;width:${width}px;letter-spacing:"0px";height:${height}px;overflow:hidden">${strChars}</td></tr>`;
    }
  }
}
export {
  AsciiEffect
};
```